# How can I deal with galvanic corrosion on my water heater?

Tags: plumbing, galvanic-corrosion

My water heater is 4 1/2 years old. Looks live galvanic corrosion. Can I get by without replacing the whole heater? Maybe just the pipes and fittings?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It does seem grounded (Green line). Photo attached. Also attached photo of a white (string thing) from hot water line to where the hot water pipe goes into the wall. Not sure if that means anything here. Hoping I won't need a new heater. I'll try having a plumber using dielectric coupling and hope they won't try to swindle me into a new heater altogether if it's not needed.

Comment: it looks like someone tied a white wire to the   Beyond bond jumper, I have seen diy do this for a washing machine it’s not a string but a individual conductor (not to code x 2)

Answer (score 1):

The fitting next to the exhaust is corroding because it is wet, likely leaking. There is no galvanic corrosion unless the dissimilar metals are wet. Water ( or other electrolyte) is necessary for an electric path for galvanic corrosion.

Answer (score 0):

I showed the pictures to a plumber and he said there's no way to tell if i need to replace the water heater or can repair it without getting in there to look. At that point if i need a new heater, i could be without water for days while waiting to get a new heater ordered. He said i could just replace the unit to avoid this happening. He also said they don't use dielectric unions anymore but instead use dielectric nipples. It sounds like if i don't want to be without water possibly for awhile, i have to get a new unit.

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts. See the [help] to merge them together.